# foreach Loop in LaTeX

Tags: latex, foreach

**Scenario:** I have a main Latex file `(main.tex)` in which I include a subfile `(appendix.tex)` using the subfiles package.

**Role of `appendix.tex`**: It further includes all the appendices as subfiles kept in an **appendix subfolder**, so that I just need to include the `appendix.tex` in the `main.tex` file.

**Current Situation:** I have to manually list the appendices in `appendix.tex` which can be cumbersome to manage.

**Target:** I want to create a `foreach` loop kind of thing in the `appendix.tex` file such that it looks in the appendix subfolder and includes each of the `.tex` files present in it.

**Question:** How can this be done?

Comment: This strikes me as a bad idea.  How can you have confidence that the script is putting together your document in the correct order, and that it isn't inserting, say, alternative drafts of some appendices?  The overhead of maintaining a list of files to include is usually slight compared to that of actually writing the appendices.

Comment: @charles The files that I want to include will be named in a convention. Possibly numbered in order. That should resolve any problems I guess? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be relatively easy implemented with `python.sty` from [here](http://www.imada.sdu.dk/~ehmsen/pythonlatex.php). This would require you to make sure that the style file and python is available on all machines were you plan to compile this document, but should be more portable than using shell scripts or preprocessors like `cpp`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably easiest done externally via a shell script. Provide some more info on your OS (Win/Apple/Linux) and someone will no doubt provide the necessary script.

Comment: I am on Win7 using the proText package for all my latex work. But I guess that should not make a difference, I wish to make the latex file compilable on every machine having latex. so no question of shell script. :)

Comment: I don't think this is possible in just LaTeX - it it is, I'd be extremely interested in how to do it. 

The following PowerShell script should do the job for you (run in the main folder to generate the appendix.tex):
dir .\appendix\*.tex | Split-Path -Leaf | foreach { "\include{$_}" } > appendix.tex

Comment: No doubt it can be improved, but hope it works. Probably worth running it before every latex run.

Answer (score 0):

I did it the other way, with a python pre-processor for LaTeX. My preprocessor generates tables and allows raw python to be put into the LaTeX file. Since `python.sty` requires that LaTeX be compiled with shell escapes, this may be a better way.

I can post the preprocessor if there is interest.

Comment: It would indeed be interesting to know about such a technique! Is it similar to Honk's answer above? :)